# HTML - embed webpage on local network

Tags: html, iframe, embed, typo3

I'm trying to embed a webpage that is running on a local host into a webpage that is running on a server in my network. The server runs a Typo3 installation.

I tried embedding the local page using an iFrame, which works great as long as I open the page from the local network. But if I try to load the webpage from the internet, loading the local page fails (obviously), as it tries to load a page under 10.0.0.X.

The local webpage is a webserver on it's own (DVB Recording Service Webserver), so there is no simple html document that I could embed. Is there any way to embed that webpage?

Thanks in advance,
Wolfram

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have 2 options:

1. You have to give your local web site a public static IP to make the iframe work in Internet.
2. In case you do not have a static IP, use a service like [DynDNS](http://dyn.com) or [No-IP](http://www.noip.com) to bind your local web server with a public domain and use this domain in your iframe.

Comment: I'm using No-IP for my Typo3 Webserver. Binding the second webserver to a public domain is unfortunately not possible, and not what I want either.

Comment: Unfortunately, the iframe will be called from the client computer, so if you want your content can be embedded and published, you have to public your second webserver or as least your desired url.